# How can I start new activity from another package?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I searched this and found many solutions but none of them works for me .

I want to start new activity from another package. I use this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,my_class.class); 
startActivityForResult(myIntent ,6161);
```

it gives this error:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.xx.yy.pack/com.xx.yy.pack.my_class}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
at com.wub.cropimage.CropImage.a(Unknown Source)
at com.wub.cropimage.CropImage.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
... 11 more
```

my manifest is here:

```
  <activity
    android:name="com.xx.yy.pack.my_class"  > 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="myintent.intent.action.Launch" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You havent showed us the lines that include `startActivity`

Comment: actually it gives error on some phones. and some phones it works.

Comment: did you tried using `IntentFilter` ?

Comment: yes it gives same error. unfortunately

Comment: but advice how can I use it? maybe I do a mistake when using IntentFilter

Comment: I add more detail about error

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,my_class.class); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Do this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="Activity1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.Activity2"></activity>
</application>
```

Note:- Activity1 is your first activity and Activity2 is your second activity
May this help you

Comment: my main activity is Activity1 ? and my second activity is Activity2? I mean which is my_class activty ?

Comment: Activity2 is your my_class activty.

Comment: The main difference is in Intent-filter as I answered.

Answer (score 0):

To call an activity from another package (application):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
myIntent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(YourPackageName);
myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivityForResult(myIntent ,6161);
```